# CentOS 6, having hard time with yum, repos and installing packages

Tags: centos, yum, python, rpm

I'm having some hard time with yum.

My end goal is to install the pymssql library for Python. It fails because it needs freetds install. `yum install freetds` fails with

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
No package freetds available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Checking at `/etc/yum.repos.d/` shows no repos, so I downloaded the `epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm` repo, then `rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`. It fails with `package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed`.

Then I tried to `yum --enablerepo=epel install freetds` but then it says `Error getting repository data for epel, repository not found`.

After doing some search I tried to see if it is indeed installed. `rpm -qa |grep -i epel` does return `epel-release-6-8.noarch`, but oddly enough, trying to remove it with `rpm -e epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm` ends up with `error: package epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm is not installed`.

Answer (score 1):

```
rpm -e epel-release
```

You remove packages using their name (not file name).

You are probably missing some files that this package reinstall. You can check with

```
rpm -V epel-release
```

But if your /etc/yum.repos.d/ is really empty then you are missing base repositories of CentOS too.

Comment: Thanks. Now `yum --enablerepo=epel install freetds` results with 2 dependencies errors, `Error: Package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libodbcinst.so.2()(64bit)` and `Error: Package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libodbc.so.2()(64bit)`. What is the best way to install these?

Comment: @DeepSpace What you are seeing are virtual provides.  There aren't packages with those exact names, but you can find out what provides them by running `repoquery --whatprovides 'libodbcinst.so.2()(64bit)'`.  That library is provided by unixODBC in the base repos.  If yum can't even see that, you have major issues.

Answer (score 0):

The freetds package is definitely in EPEL for CentOS 6.  If there is nothing in `/etc/yum.repos.d`, then someone must have manually deleted the repo files.  I suggest running `rpm -Va` to see how many files have been tampered with.  `centos-release` should have five files in that directory.  `epel-release` should have two files.